# Php regex to conditionally replace first occurance of string

Tags: php, regex

I need to do some cleanup on strings that look like this:

```
$author_name = '<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Jones_Burdette>Robert Jones Burdette </a>';
```

Notice the href tag doesn't have closing quotes - I'm using the DOMParser on a large table of these to extract the text, and it borks on this.

I would like to look at the string in $author_name;

IF the first > does NOT have a " before it, replace it with "> to close the tag correctly. If it is okay, just skip and do the next step. Be sure not to replace the second > at all.

Using php regex, I haven't been able to find a working solution - I could chop up the whole thing and check its parts, but that would be slow and I think there must be a regex that can do what I want.

TIA

Comment: Get rid of the '</a>' by searching it's position and removing with substring (or regex replace). Then search for '>' or '"' or whatever.

Comment: that doesn't really do much for me..I don't want to chop it up & rework it, I want to check if the condition exists with a regex, then replace (hopefully all in the same go)

Comment: Why do you want to do it with regex so bad?

Comment: because I have a table with 20,000 values to be analyzed & I think a regex will be most efficient. It doesn't have to be, but I know how to do it other ways. My question is how to do it with a regex

Comment: echo preg_replace('/(.+)[\'"]?>(.+)/', '$1">$2', $author_name);

Comment: If it's a one time thing, and you don't have a time limit, it doesn't have to be efficient. I think you would have been done by now either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is, find the first closing tag, with or without the double-quote ("), and replace it with (">):

```
$author_name = preg_replace('/(.+?)"?>(.+?)/', '$1">$2', $author_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.barattalo.it/html-fixer/

Download that, then include it in your php.
The rest is quite easy:

```
$dirty_html = ".....bad html here......";

$a = new HtmlFixer();
$clean_html = $a->getFixedHtml($dirty_html);
```

It's common for people to want to use regular expressions, but you must remember that [HTML is not regular](http://welbog.homeip.net/glue/53/XML_is_not_regular).

Comment: interesting project - I'll have a look. but surely there is a simple regex to deal with this one case that pops up 20 times or so from a db table, rather than run the whole thing through a char-by-char analysis library?

Comment: @jmadsen, please take a peek at my edit to show why I believe you shouldn't use regex.

Comment: yes, but this is a very specific case where one person has seemingly made the same mistake in many places, but I cannot clean the live data. I am cleaning it for the DomParser to handle correctly